# Disable automatic etag header in Rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, caching, etag

Rails automatically adds etag to all responses.
How can I change this behaviour?
I found some examples for rails 2.x, but it doesn't work.

Comment: You need to disable caching, right?

Comment: Yes, we don't want headers to be added.

Comment: Did you figure out when/where Rails is adding/generating etag to all responses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could disable caching in your config/environments/*.rb files with:

```
config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
```

ian.